# Azure: Error creating or updating virtual machine AzureMolyVM1 - Azure Error: SkuNotAvailable

Tags: azure, ansible

I am trying to create a VM on Azure. I have a pay as you go subscription plan but currently still on the free hours.

The challenge is I am not able to find a single VM that is available in ANY region. I go to create virtual machine, then I select the link to pick a VM size and ALL sizes are disable. I am not able to select anything.

Next thing I tried is using Ansible. On powershell, I can see that the image is very well available in my zone.

```
$ az vm image list -f CentOS -l canadacentral
[
  {
    "offer": "CentOS",
    "publisher": "OpenLogic",
    "sku": "7.5",
    "urn": "OpenLogic:CentOS:7.5:latest",
    "urnAlias": "CentOS",
    "version": "latest"
  }
]
```

But creating a VM with this image throws following error:

```
"Error creating or updating virtual machine azuremolyvm3 - Azure Error: SkuNotAvailable\nMessage: 
The requested size for resource 
'/subscriptions/fgfgfgfg-4cf4-43b8-b29f-f6448ecf09bd/resourceGroups/molygp/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/azuremolyvm3' is currently not available in location 'canadacentral' zones '' for subscription 'fgfgfgfg-4cf4-43b8-b29f-f6448ecf09bd'. 

Please try another size or deploy to a different location or zones. 
See https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable for details.",
```

What am I missing?

Comment: 1. please hide your subscription id. 2. what is your create script look like? Can you sleect the size in Azure Portal? 3. Please check following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-sku-not-available

Comment: Azure is such a frustration for me! I cannot select any vm-size, all are disabled. The subscription id in the code above is masked. The link to microsoft says open a request when you go to open a request it says you have either to upgrade to paid monthly plan or use community support :(.

Comment: then its related to "pay as you go" subscription and you have to use a different location - one of the US locations should work. But you should be able to create a support ticket in Azure Portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/sku-series-unavailable